# How to produce mixed-case abbreviations with glossaries-extra and small-caps style?

Tags: glossaries-extra

I am using the glossaries-extra package for abbreviations in a technical document using a small-caps style for abbreviations (`\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc}`).
The text contains a lot of mixed-case abbreviations (like qPCR, rRNA) which I would like to typeset in a mix of lowercase and small caps letters (like `q\textsc{pcr}`).

How can I do this with glossaries-extra? I will have to tell the package somehow which letters should be protected from applying small caps.
Ideally, I would like to write `qPCR` in my definition of the abbreviation and have glossaries-extra transform the upper-case letters to small caps, because that is most convenient. However, I would also be satisfied with a solution where I have to indicate lower-case letters explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use an extra category for mixed-case abbreviations. I can then use an abbreviation style that does format abbreviations with small caps, and apply the small caps manually.
For example:

```
% Set different abbreviation styles for different categories
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc}
\setabbreviationstyle[mixedcase]{long-short}

% Apply small-caps formatting for mixed-case abbreviations manually
\newabbreviation{pcr}{pcr}{polymerase chain reaction}
\newabbreviation[category=mixedcase]{qpcr}{q\textsc{pcr}}{quantitative \glsxtrp{short}{pcr}}
```

The disadvantage of this is that if I want to change my abbreviation style (for example, use full caps instead of small caps), I would have to change the definition of all the mixed-case abbreviations.
I would be happy if someone has a better idea how to do this.